# Challenges with 'INSERT' query using dblink_exec

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I've read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib-dblink-exec.html) repeatedly, but I'm unclear why I keep getting a

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into"
```

On

```
SELECT dblink_exec ('dbname=database_test',
insert into public.names (gid,name,"default",class,last_updated,description) 
values ('124565555','dblink_test','true','10','2017-01-30 14:14:40.581',null));
```

Can I not INSERT to a remote db (note: 'database_test' .is on the same server as the database I am working in)

Answer (score 0):

According to docs you should single quote `'` sql statement.

```
SELECT dblink_exec('myconn', 'insert into foo values(21,''z'',''{"a0","b0","c0"}'');');
```

Comment: why have you added an answer? can edit your question.

Comment: try to execute your sentence outside the dblink, maybe it is not correct.